# Is it possible to set the column width of a grid in GWT using uibinder?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

I'm trying to use the GWT grid component in uibinder. It works fine until I want to set the width of the columns. The following is what I've tried to do but it doesn't seem to work.

```
        <g:Grid width="100%">
        <g:row>
            <g:customCell width="20%">
                <g:FlowPanel width="">
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:customCell>
            <g:customCell width="80%">
                <g:FlowPanel width="">
                </g:FlowPanel>
            </g:customCell>
        </g:row>
    </g:Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only `styleName` is taken into account on `g:row`, `g:cell` and `g:customCell` elements.

If you can (i.e. if your grid content is mostly static), avoid using `Grid` and prefer an `HTMLPanel` containing an HTML `<table>`, this gives you much more flexibility.

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/tags/2.4.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/uibinder/elementparsers/GridParser.java

Answer (score 7):

You can write some java code in order to do that, example:

```
    grid.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(0, "10%");
    grid.getColumnFormatter().setWidth(1, "10%");
```